# Use different classes for possible null values (C# used as example)

Tags: c#, class, structure

I have made a class with the following properties

```
class Human
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following methods declared in my api service

```
public async Task<List<Human>> GetAllHumans() 
{
    // Using mock data (would call the api service here)
    return new List<Human>
    {
        new Human { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" },
        new Human { FirstName = "Jane", LastName = "Doe" }
    };
}

public async Task<Human> GetDetailedInformationForHuman(Human human)
{
    // Retrieves data from the server for more detailed information
    var extraInformation = /* Api Call */
    human.Age = extraInformation.Age;
    human.Address = extraInformation.Address;
    return human;
}
```

There is no way to get a more detailed version of human from the GetAllHumans method. (With the Age and Address property already set.)

Should I created a different class (for example "DetailedHuman") and move the Age and Address properties to there and inherit from Human. Since when Im using a Human type in my program. I am always not sure if Age or Address are null unless I check them. What's the best practice for a situation like this? Thank you for taking your time.

Edit 1:
My second example, as a requested from a comment was creating a second class and putting the properties as such.

```
class Human
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

class DetailedHuman : Human
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

public async Task<List<Human>> GetAllHumans() 
{
    // Using mock data (would call the api service here)
    return new List<Human>
    {
        new Human { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" },
        new Human { FirstName = "Jane", LastName = "Doe" }
    };
}

public async Task<DetailedHuman> GetDetailedInformationForHuman(Human human)
{
    // Retrieves data from the server for more detailed information
    var extraInformation = /* Api Call */
    var detailedHuman = new DetailedHuman { FirstName = human.FirstName, LastName = human.LastName };
    detailedHuman.Age = extraInformation.Age;
    detailedHuman.Address = extraInformation.Address;
    return detailedHuman;
}
```

Comment: i don't get the problem and the question due to punctuation i think. could you please elabtorate last paragraph

Comment: While `Human` class is mutable you have to check always.

Comment: What problem exactly are you trying to solve? What does the consuming code look like, and why is that problematic? If something can or can't be there, you'll have to check for null anyway.

Comment: @CodeCaster The problem is that I am not exactly sure if having null values in a class that have the properties declared is a bad thing. Because they may be null or they may not be, depending on the information our server has. But, this might be confusing for other developers using my api code. Because they might have no idea why some of the information isn't filled and some isn't. So I'm looking for a 'best practice' for this scenario. So that I won't have to confuse other developers. So I was thinking of the same idea as Fabjan. But to me that still doesn't look like a good solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches to this problem:

**Approach #1: inheritance (your example)**

```
class Human
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

class DetailedHuman : Human
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Pros: you can use polymorphism (you can pass the instance of `DetailedHuman` to the code that requires instance of `Human` class).

Cons: you might run into the situations (depending on your use cases) where you have to do type checks: `if (human is DetailedHuman) { ... }` or casts: `DetailedHuman detailedHuman = human as DetailedHuman; if (detailedHuman != null) { ... }`.

I would recommend using this approach when you definitely need to use the polymorphism.

**Approach #2: totally separate classes**

```
class Human
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

class DetailedHuman
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

You can also add copy constructor to `DetailedHuman` like this:

```
public DetailedHuman(Human human)
{
    FirstName = human.FirstName;
    LastName = human.LastName;
}
```

Pros:

1. The most flexible approach — you can add/remove any fields to/from these classes since they are totally independent of each other.
2. The complexity of the code is lower comparing to other approaches (although the total amount of the code will probably be larger).

Cons: you wouldn't be able to use generic or polymorphic code which may lead to the code duplication.

I usually choose this approach in the beginning of the project when requirements are not totally clear and the number of additional fields in `DetailedHuman` class is relatively low (I would say five additional fields or less). The benefit of this approach is that you can easily change the the structure of the types to reflect the changes in the requirements. Additionally you can easily switch to inheritance or aggregation approach once requirements become clearer and you see that your code would definitely benefit from such switch.

**Approach #3: aggregation**

The same concept as in @Fabjan's example although I would suggest using it in slightly different way:

```
class HumanName
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

class Human
{
    public HumanName Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Pros:

1. You don't have to copy all the common fields. There would be only one assignment operation: `human.Name = humanName`.
2. You can pass the `human.Name` to the code that requires `HumanName` type.
3. You can have additional inner sets like

   ```
   class HumanCredentials
   {
       public string Login { get; set; }
       public string AccessToken { get; set; }
   }

   class Human
   {
       public HumanName Name { get; set; }
       public HumanCredentials Credentials { get; set; }
       public int Age { get; set; }
       public string Address { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   which cannot be done using inheritance approach.

Cons:

1. You wouldn't be able to handle cases when you need to add a new field to the `HumanName` type but don't want to add it to the `Human` type.
2. You would have to write stuff like `human.Name.FirstName` which sometimes may be tedious.

With regard to your code the first method in this case will return `List<HumanName>` and the second will return `Human` object based on `HumanName`.

I usually choose this approach when the number of additional fields is relatively large (> 5) or when the chances of requirement changes that lead to the change of these field sets in the future are small.

All of these approaches assume that you have the situation where `Human` and `DetailedHuman` are essentially the same domain entity (there is "is-a" relationship between them: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a). Another example would be having the database table with all the fields (FirstName, LastName, Age, Address) so the `Human` class (or `HumanName` in the approach #3) is just a subset of these fields (in other terms: `Human` is a projection of the `DetailedHuman` class). If it is not the case then it means that there is a higher chance that the structure of the types may change in the future so in such situation I would definitely suggest either approach #2 or #3 depending on your use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'd recommend against inheritance here. If we expect that some data might or might not be populated we'll have to check it anyway. We can reduce number of checks by adding *new* class `Details` with all optional fields and put it inside `Human` class :

```
class Details 
{
   public int Age { get; set; }
   public string Address { get; set; }
}

class Human
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Details Details { get; set; }
}
```

Now we can check if *all* details data were populated  just by checking one property :

```
if(human.Details != null) { do smth when all data was populated by service... }
else { do smth when only FirstName and LastName were populated }
```

Or using C# 6.0 we can safely access property we need without risk of throwing NullReferenceException just with one line of code :

```
human?.Details.Address
```

Comment: Yes, but you still have to perform a test.  Since testing is required for this solution it is just as easy to have only one class and check if Age and Address is null in the one class.

Comment: But I still don't think this is an optimal solution. Let's say that I will add this property to my human (which may be available in the detailed version) public Date PassedAwayDate { get; set; }. This may be the case for John Doe, but it's not a required property. Then I would have to do 2 checks. And Details also seems a little out of place but it's a step in the right direction. Thanks for answering. PS I think you meant human.Details?.Address instead of human?.Details.Address.

Comment: @Elertan If we use code `Details?.Address`, it'll only check property of Details, and when we'll access other properties we'll have to check each of them, meaning that we gained nothing by introducing this Details class. The idea is to either fill Details class the way, that it'll never containg `null` values or leave the `human.Details` property `null` signalizing that values were not populated by api service and there is no need for further checks